# Difference in usage of 'such' in 2 sentences that probably mean the same

Tags: difference

What is the difference between these 2 sentences?

*1. Audi has grown to compete with such cars as Lamborghini.*
*2. Audi has grown to compete with cars such as Lamborghini.*

To me, both sentences seem to mean the same. Is there any unapparent difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct and mean the same thing, but the latter sounds much better to me. I think the problem is that **such as** is most often grouped together so it sounds a little strange when it is separated.

You have a small semantic issue though. I would say that Audi and Lamborghini are car **manufacturers** in this context. Although cars are often referred to by their manufacturer's name, the cars themselves don't grow.

```
[The company] has grown to compete with [other companies] such as [CompanyX]
```

rather than

```
[The company] has grown to compete with [cars] such as [CompanyX]
```

> Audi has grown to compete with car manufacturers such as Lamborghini.